# API не работает. Не могу вытащить значения

Tags: php, html, api

Есть код

```
<?php 
$json= curl_init(); 
$json=json_decode($response,true);
$json=end($json['data']);


foreach($json as $val) { ?>
<?
$mapping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://site.com/airlines/airlines.json'));
$name = '';
$code = $val['destination'];
foreach ($mapping as $item) {
    if ($item->iata == $code) {
        $name = $item->name;
        $departure = $item->departure_at;
        break;
    }
}
?>
<div style="background:#ffffff; color:#008BE0!important;font-weight:bold;">Вылет: <?=$val['departure_at']?> Цена: <?=$val['price']?> Авиакомпания: <?=$name?> Номер рейса: <?=$val['flight_number']?></div>
.....

<?php } ?>
```

У API Ответ:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"AAQ":{"origin":"REN","destination":"AAQ","price":15450,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":5833,"departure_at":"2016-02-13T09:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-02-20T18:05:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-09T03:29:22Z"},"AER":{"origin":"REN","destination":"AER","price":15450,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":5831,"departure_at":"2016-03-22T19:30:00Z","return_at":"2016-03-25T12:35:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-08T07:02:03Z"},"DYU":{"origin":"REN","destination":"DYU","price":25927,"transfers":0,"airline":"SZ","flight_number":212,"departure_at":"2016-02-10T14:10:00Z","return_at":"2016-02-24T09:30:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-06T16:54:52Z"},"EVN":{"origin":"REN","destination":"EVN","price":23026,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":5833,"departure_at":"2016-02-19T09:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-03-04T06:05:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-08T16:14:51Z"},"KRR":{"origin":"REN","destination":"KRR","price":15450,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":1249,"departure_at":"2016-02-20T21:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-02-23T06:30:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-08T04:22:20Z"},"LBD":{"origin":"REN","destination":"LBD","price":31345,"transfers":2,"airline":"U6","flight_number":2625,"departure_at":"2016-07-12T17:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-07-13T21:40:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-06T18:21:49Z"},"LED":{"origin":"REN","destination":"LED","price":9599,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":1245,"departure_at":"2016-02-27T05:55:00Z","return_at":"2016-04-24T06:25:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-07T18:45:53Z"},"MOW":{"origin":"REN","destination":"MOW","price":8250,"transfers":0,"airline":"FV","flight_number":6754,"departure_at":"2016-06-09T07:40:00Z","return_at":"2016-06-09T18:45:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-06T19:17:10Z"},"NUX":{"origin":"REN","destination":"NUX","price":20000,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":1249,"departure_at":"2016-03-14T21:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-04-15T16:05:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-07T03:38:33Z"},"SIP":{"origin":"REN","destination":"SIP","price":15450,"transfers":1,"airline":"SU","flight_number":5833,"departure_at":"2016-02-17T09:00:00Z","return_at":"2016-02-24T15:15:00Z","expires_at":"2016-02-06T17:18:48Z"}},"error":null,"currency":"rub"}
```

Код рабочий, я его использовал для другого АПИ, но здесь вот с этой частью не могу разобраться

```
foreach ($mapping as $item) {
        if ($item->iata == $code) {
            $name = $item->name;
            $departure = $item->departure_at;
            break;
        }
```

Спасибо, с уважением.

Answer (score 1):

А вы могли бы более подробно объяснить, что вы хотите?

Потому что ваш код, в принципе, рабочий. Хотя, я не вижу необходимости, если вы работаете с массивами, переходить на объекты.

Вообще, если вам нужны коды аэропортов, то перебирайте именно входящий массив data по ключам и значениям:

```
$mapping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://site.com/airlines/airlines.json'), true);
$name = '';
$code = $val['destination'];
foreach ($mapping['data'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($key == $code) {
        $name = $item['name'];
        $departure = $item['departure_at'];
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Не подумал в начале о самой этой конструкции... можно гораздо проще:

Вместо всего `foreach ($mapping['data'] as $key => $item)` обратиться напрямую сразу:

```
if (isset($mapping['data'][$code])) {
    $name = $mapping['data'][$code]['name'];
    $departure = $mapping['data'][$code]['departure_at'];
}
```

Comment: Станислав Вот как тут мне надо http://air-tickets.su/Neryungri.html Раздел на этой странице чуть ниже "Популярные города"

Comment: Ну так вы мой вариант попробуйте. Просто когда вы свой пример привели, у вас там изначально ошибка была - форич перебирал массив ДАТА, т.е. в своем ифе вы не получали ничего... А если скормить форичу сам массив ДАТА, тогда, используя ключи, вы получите свой код, как ключ, а так же имя и вылет.

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Станислав все работает только вот destination через <?=$val['destination']?> не выводится

Comment: Так если вы в $code записали этот $val['destination'], как он у вас может не выводиться? Вы попробуйте посмотреть, что у вас вообще в первом foreach происходит: foreach($json as $val) ... выведите значения на экран, например: print_r($val)

Answer (score 0):

Я понял так - второй foreach перебирает по справочнику авиалиний - и если нашел тот который совпадает code - забирает значения по неявному обращению к ключам структуры. Возможно ошибка в том что в качестве пункта вылета берется базовый аэропорт компании

Comment: Сергей, я уже и не знаю где ошибка)

Comment: `        $departure = $item->departure_at; `

Comment: Сергей вы можете со мной по чату пообщаться? Киньте ссылку на чат, где мы сможем поговорить?

Comment: @Arcadiy Не создавайте клоны вопросов. [Ссылка на чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35390/room-for-http-ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-489653)

Comment: @tutankhamun
Приглашаю